# Pause processing on end of shift

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I've got a resourcePool of capacity 1 with a defined on/off schedule. A assembler block seizes the resource and then delays it. If the on/off schedule turns the resource off while there is an agent in the assembler delay, I found two options:
1. The resource stays until the delay is finished and resource is released.
2. The agent is kicked out immediately and the resource released.

None of those do match a real world situation. If I get to the end of a shift probably nobody is going to finish his work unless it's absolutely necessary. Neither will anyone throw out a semi-finished product.

It would be more realistic if the worker would just pause the processing and continue working on the same agent the next day.

I'm probably just missing some settings. Is there a easy way to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how you found those options, but the correct way of doing this is by using the preemption option in the assembler block:

[image: preemption]

To accomplish what you want you would have to use the "wait for original resource" option, or the seize any resource option (same result since you only have one resource). The task preemption policy defines what happens with your agents when the resource is taken by a shift ending or by a task with higher priority.